# Logging NAT mappings on a Mikrotik router

Tags: firewall, routing, nat, mikrotik

I am looking for suggestions on how to configure a Mikrotik router to log NAT session setup and ideally teardown.  However, setup only is sufficient for my immediate needs.

I found a method to log all packets, and I might be able to reduce this to only logging the TCP SYN, FIN, and RST packets, but I have not yet found that method.  This doesn't cover UDP, which I would also like to track.  For UDP, it's fine if a session times out and re-appears as a new session again.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned which *method* you have found, as [standard logging function](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:System/Log) in RouterOS will not log such info.
These information are only available through [Connection Tracking](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/Firewall/Connection_tracking), if you meant that, and since Mikrotik doesn't offer any option to export it fully or to send it to remote syslog host, so I guess, there is very little chance to implement what you are trying to.

See this discussion here: http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=53483